# How to insert word on specific position in vector Keras

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, keras, classification

How to insert word on specific position in vector using Keras and pad_sequence?

For example I have sentence:

```
1) XYZ1 is a specific word
2) Specific word is a XYZ1
```

Above we have 5 unique tokens:

```
XYZ1: 1, is: 2, a: 3, specific: 4, word: 5
```

My max length of sequence in pad_sequence is equal 10.

If I use text_to_sequences i got:

```
1) [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
2) [4, 5, 2, 3, 1]
```

After that I use pad_sequence(maxlen = 10)

```
1) [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
2) [4, 5, 2, 3, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

My problem is how to insert word such as XYZ1 always in specific position in vector, for example on first or center position of vector and have around another words.

I want this for classification.

Edit:

```
1)XYZ1 is a specific word
2) Hello, my name is BBB2 and I tell you
3) Your doing it AAA2 wrong
```

I have these specific word in my data(as first column(XYZ1, BBB2, AAA2)) and I want insert this words in a exactly position in vector. If I decide to insert it in central, output vector:

```
[0, 1 , 2, 3, BBB2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```

All words must be in the same position in vector.

Comment: It's not quite clear what you're trying to achieve. Can you provide a couple of examples for different inputs?

Comment: @EliKorvigo check my edit

Comment: So, you want the position of "special words" in the output to be invariant of their position in the input?

Comment: It should be simple for you to do this if you place the word always as the 1st word. 1. filter out the word you are interested in your raw input 2. always place the filtered word at the beginning of your input

You should be able to do this completely offline.